# Using `Application.LoadComponent` with dependency injection

Tags: wpf, xaml, f#, code-behind

I have a XAML file in an F# project. The XAML file is built as a resource (not a BAML-compiled page).

In order to dynamically load the page, I use the `Application.LoadComponent` method with an appropriate URI to find the resource. This works fine (albeit slowly).

Also, in order to specialize the component (e.g. a Window), I create a custom `MainWindow` class which inherits from `Window`. This also works fine.

```
type MainWindow() =
    inherit Window()
```

The problem now arises when introducing dependency injection via `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. The issue is that `LoadComponent` does not know how to use my custom-built DI container to inject constructor arguments for `MainWindow` (e.g. it could require a FooService):

```
type MainWindow(foo: FooService) =
    inherit Window()
```

Indeed, WPF knows nothing of this external service provider, since I have not told it about it.

Is there some kind of WPF magic one can use to hook into the `LoadComponent` machinery and ensure that dependency injection works?

This is not an issue in C# where BAML compilation ensures there is a cohesive compiled class that embodies both the XAML and the code-behind, and the programmer need not be concerned with manually loading the XAML.

In F# the story is different, and I do not know how to introduce dependency injection into the WPF machinery. Since `Application.LoadComponent` does not have any overloads to supply a service provider, I was wondering whether there is some other mechanism to do this.

My fallback approach is to grab a global reference to the service provider in the MainWindow class initialization code, a la:

```
type MainWindow() =

    inherit Window()

    let servicerProvider = AppHost.Services
    let foo = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<FooService>()
```

The whole DI-business seems a bit dicey for this use-case, especially for child windows, but for now I am pursuing this avenue, since the framework I have started using, is also using it.

Comment: It's usual not to have any service dependencies in UI classes such as window or page. Instead, logic requiring such things goes in viewmodels. In fact it's possible to have just the one window defined and everything goes in an instance of that as content. Could you expand on the pattern of usage of these dynamically loaded things? Eg do you know all about what'll be there at compile time?

Comment: The WPF-UI framework seems to have this approach in its gallery sample app. I’m trying to use that franework in an idiomatic way. 

https://github.com/lepoco/wpfui/blob/main/src/Wpf.Ui.Gallery/Views/Windows/MainWindow.xaml.cs

Comment: @Andy *"It's usual not to have any service dependencies in UI classes such as window or page."* - UI classes are classes like any other. As such they are designed to use aggregation/composition. This naturally introduces dependencies. The most common dependency of a UI type is its data context. UI classes, like any other classes have dependencies. The fact that a class is considered a "UI class" is based on abstracted application models and has no influence on the class as a logical OO entity, a compiler type or language construct.

Comment: @Andy *"Instead, logic requiring such things goes in viewmodels"* - That's too broad to be acceptable. You definitely don't move code from view to the view model only because the code introduces a dependency. The *only* reason to move code from view to view model is when the code was wrongfully associated with the view before. Aside from that, it doesn't make sense to move dependencies from view to view model with the goal to eliminate the dependency when the view will always depend on the view model by definition.

Comment: @Andy I'm not writing this as an offense or to challenge you, but because there is already enough misconception about MVVM. Your statements are wrong and only confuse people who could come across these uncommented comment of yours.

Comment: The statement is supported by your own answer. I've seen a fair bit of wpf built to mvvm. Parameterless constructors are very common for UI. There may be code but nothing is injected via DI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that the whole XAML engine is built around the constraint that all types that are instantiated by the engine must declare a default constructor as this is the only constructor that the engine will invoke. Without any type information how can the engine know how to construct a type to satisfy the constructor dependencies? XAMl is still a markup language.

Instead, types used in XAML are usually *initialized* via the dependency property infrastructure e.g., a property default or property inheritance, and *configured* using data binding or by defining a `Style` or by setting properties locally.

> *"My fallback approach is to grab a global reference to the service provider in the MainWindow class initialization code"*

That's a terrible idea and is not *Dependency Injection*. That's the *Service Locator*, the infamous anti-pattern that causes more harm than it solves problems and is usually avoidable. Using *Singleton* or *Service Locator* design patterns when applying the *Dependency Injection* pattern is totally pointless and adds absolutely redundant complexity as they effectively nullify the efficiency of *Dependency Injection*. *Dependency Injection* is usually used to eliminate both of those anti-patterns.
Making everything static violates so many good and important principles and is guaranteed to lead to smelly code. Because the referenced variables are static, following your pattern will make your complete application smell.

Whenever you feel like sharing the IoC container, don't do it. Instead, **use a factory**. Always.
*Abstract Factory* is a powerful creational design pattern that solves many problems related to type instantiation.

The recommended solution is:

1. Wrap the `Application.LoadComponent` call for a specific type into a dedicated factory.
2. You define the dependencies of the XAML type as dependencies of this factory.
3. Then you register the factory with the IoC container like any other type so that all dependencies are resolved and provided by the IoC container. If some of these dependencies are not shared instances, the factory itself must receive dedicated factories in order to create instances of the XAML type's transient dependencies dynamically.
4. Next provide the dependencies to the instance which is returned from `Application.LoadComponent` by assigning them either to

   - a) a custom `InitializeComponent` method, declared by the XAML type, and that defines all the dependencies that would normally be defined by the constructor (recommended)
   - b) or to public properties.

   You should not declare properties as `public` only for this purpose. If those properties must be hidden, then use variant *a)*.
   *a)* is the most graceful solution as it doesn't require the factory to know any details about the type (the fewer the better). The factory simply has to provide the argument list for the initialization method.
5. Add the properly constructed type to the visual tree and use it.

Another solution could be to inject *all* dependencies into the `MainWindow` and make it expose them via read-only dependency properties and then let your UI elements bind to those properties to get their dependencies. This may work for small scenarios, especially where the dependency is a shared instance, but this usually violates common data hiding principles.

For your particular case a factory for each XAML type, that wraps the `Application.LoadComponent` call, is the cleanest way and most common way.

> *"The whole DI-business seems a bit dicey for this use-case, especially for child windows"*

Now you know that you can solve all this kind of problems by injecting factories for the type where creation is problematic.
For example, when the parent `Window` receives the factory to create the child `Window` (e.g. a dialog) then all the dependencies and configuration details are hidden and encapsulated in this factory. The parent can create types of the child without having itself to depend on the child's dependencies only to delegate them.
*Abstract Factory* is the omni present companion of the *Dependency Injection* design pattern.